# Add to cart doesn't stick in IE11 - IE ASP.NET session cookie changes on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, nopcommerce-3.80

We're using Nop Commerce 3.8.

When we add an item to the cart when using Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Opera, it works fine. But when we do it when using IE, it appears to add the item to the cart, but it doesn't stick - the item shows up in the fly out cart on the details page just after adding it to the cart, but if you refresh the page or navigate to the cart page, the shopping cart is empty.

I checked the cookies, and on the shopping cart page it looks like the NopCustomer cookie is present and correct, but the ASP.Net session id changes with each page refresh or navigation.

The protocol and domain / host aren't changing, that part of the url is staying the same, and there's no redirect happening, so. I'm not sure what is going on and why it is only happening on IE.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing that?

I notice that the ASP.NET session cookie's expiration shows up as being set to "End of session." Does that have a different or unsupported meaning for IE?

Comment: maybe better go to [official support](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/)?

Comment: Well, the nop commerce code base is open source, and at the moment the budget for this project is such that paying for support is not an easy sell. Maybe I should rephrase the title or the early part of the question and remove the nop commerce tag. If you're building a web site using ASP.NET MVC (which is what nop commerce based site developers are basically doing), and the session id is changing between page views.. is that really specifically a nop commerce issue? I mentioned the nop commerce part to illustrate the effect of the changing session id.

Comment: Can you provide a simplest demo to github and let us test/reproduce the issue?

Comment: You can see it if you go to http://gtp_high.team24x7fundraising.com using IE11. I'll see if I can get something posted to github.

Comment: I just tried and reproduced the issue, upvoted.

Comment: Turns out IE blocks cookies on domains with underscores in them. Man, those Redmond boys sure march the beat of their own drummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason for it. IE blocks cookies on domains with underscores in them. This is kind of old stuff, but it appears to still be in effect:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/08/20/internet-explorer-cookie-internals-faq/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316112/prb-session-variables-do-not-persist-between-requests-after-you-install-internet-explorer-security-patch-ms01-055